# How to do dynamic routing with next13

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-rewrites

I'm fairly new to nextjs 13, especially with the app router, I have a very big project in react that I would like to migrate and I know it won't be an easy road, I've started to tackle a bit of the future challenges, starting with routing.

I will have a lot of routes, but for now let's focus on one, we will call it "section", and the path will be something like : `/:section?/:subsection?`

Routing with nextjs has always been kind of mystical to me, I know react-router really well but not the folder logic by the nextjs team.

I know typical routing in nextjs is folder directed, like `app/section/page.tsx`, `app/about/[id]` etc

Thing is, I don't know these things in my case, because they are fully dynamical, I've searched in the nextjs doc but could not find an easy answer.

My ideal project folder will be something like `src/app/section/page.tsx`, `src/app/post/page.tsx`, etc

I have gone the path of rewrites, in the `next-config.js` file, but I can't make it work.

I can retrieve the query params in the main page, through the props given by nextjs, but I can't retrieve it in a client component through any of the hooks.

I have done a codesanbox of course, to give you a reproducing code.

To reproduce, navigate to an url like `/one/two`, and look at both the browser and node console.

The repo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/brave-dew-sh75dc

Everything in the description

Comment: For a dynamic section structure, your folder setup should be: `sections/[section]/page.tsx` and `sections/[section]/[subsection]/page.tsx`. In `page.tsx` under `[section]`, you'll have access to a `section` prop. In the `[subsection]/page.tsx`, both `section` and `subsection` will be available as page props. It's all clearly laid out in their docs and I recommend reading the 10 or so pages https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing

Comment: What if I also want to handle urls like `/:section/:subsection/:slug(.*)-id([0-9]*)` ? I want to be able to restrict this tight with previously used in a react-router world regex

Comment: You'd add another level deep like the above - `[slug]/page.tsx`. You can't regex in the folder like your comment. You can check in the page if the slug matches your regex and throw a 404. All of this info is in the docs - nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing

Answer (score 0):

Next.js uses file-based router. Here are some solution for your routing cases in the question and the comments:

To make a dynamic route, you can use `[slug]` format in folder name. It can be nested at any level of nesting. You can make `src/app/[section]/[subscription]/page.tsx`

You can then read the `section` and `subscription` values in page.js (as well as layout.js) via the props:

```js
// src/app/[section]/[subscription]/page.tsx
export default function Page({params}) {
  const {sectionl, subscription} = params;
}
```

Or in Client Components via `useParams` hook:

```js
'use client'
 
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const params = useParams<{ section: string; subscription: string }>()
}
```

You can also, use [`useSelectedLayoutSegment`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-selected-layout-segment) and [`useSelectedLayoutSegments`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-selected-layout-segments) in Client Components under layout.

To read the query params e.g. `?id=123` in a page.js you can use the prop `searchParams`

```js
export default function Page({ searchParams }) {
  const id = searchParams.id;
}
```

Or using `useSearchParams` in ClientComponents:

```js
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const id = searchParams.get("id");
}
```

To implement `/:section/:subsection/:slug(.*)-id([0-9]*)` You could make `src/app/[section]/[subscription]/[slug]/page.js` with Self-healing URL.

This Blog explains Self-healing URLs very well:

- https://mikebifulco.com/posts/self-healing-urls-nextjs-seo